# How to push files into my github repo using jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have tried with some commands in a build --> windows batch command, but getting error as,

> error: src refspec master does not match

Commands which I have typed were below :

```
start "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Git\Git Bash.exe"

git add .
git commit 
git push origin master
```

Comment: Why not use theJenkins [git plugin publisher](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#git-publisher-options) options?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            steps {
                // Create a dummy file in the repo
                sh('echo \$BUILD_NUMBER > example-\$BUILD_NUMBER.md')
            }
        }
        stage("Commit") {
            steps {
                sh('''
                    git checkout -B $TARGET_BRANCH
                    git config user.name 'my-ci-user'
                    git config user.email 'my-ci-user@users.noreply.github.example.com'
                    git add . && git commit -am "[Jenkins CI] Add build file"
                ''')
            }
        }
        stage("Push") {
            environment { 
                GIT_AUTH = credentials('support-team-up') 
            }
            steps {
                sh('''
                    git config --local credential.helper "!f() { echo username=\\$GIT_AUTH_USR; echo password=\\$GIT_AUTH_PSW; }; f"
                    git push origin HEAD:$TARGET_BRANCH
                ''')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for more details you can follow this link : [jenkins-pipeline](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360027646491-Pipeline-Equivalent-to-Git-Publisher?page=27)